# Snakemake: parameterized runs that re-use intermediate output files

Tags: snakemake

here is a complex problem that I am struggling to find a clean solution for:

Imagine having a Snakemake workflow with several rules that can be parameterized in some way. Now, we might want to test different parameter settings for some rules, to see how the results differ. However, ideally, if these rules depend on the output of other rules that are not parameterized, we want to re-use these non-changing files, instead of re-computing them for each of our parameter settings. Furthermore, if at all possible, all this should be optional, so that in the default case, a user does not see any of this.

There is inherent complexity in there (to specify which files are re-used, etc). I am also aware that this is not exactly the intended use case of Snakemake ("reproducible workflows"), but is more of a meta-feature for experimentation.

Here are some approaches:

- Naive solution: Add wildcards for each possible parameter to the file paths. This gets ugly, hard to maintain, and hard to extend really quickly. Not a solution.
- A nice approach might be to name each run, and have an individual config file for that name which contains all settings that we need. Then, we only need a wildcard for such a named set of parameter settings. That would probably require to read some table of meta-config file, and process that. That doesn't solve the re-use issue though. Also, that means we need multiple config files for one snakemake call, and it seems that this is not possible (they would instead update each other, but not considered as individual configs to be run separately).
- Somehow use sub-workflows, by specifying individual config files each time, e.g., via a wildcard. Not sure that this can be done (e.g., `configfile: path/to/{config_name}.yaml`). Still not a solution for file re-using.
- Quick-and-dirty: Run all the rules up to the last output file that is shared between different configurations. Then, manually (or with some extra script) create directories with symlinks to this "base" run, with individual config files that specify the parameters for the per-config-runs. This still necessitates to call snakemake individually for each of these directories, making cluster usage harder.

None of these solve all issues though. Any ideas appreciated!

Thanks in advance, all the best
Lucas

Comment: I've been thinking about this before as well. The "best" I could come up with (but I never implemented it) is to calculate e.g. a shasum over the relevant parameters and add this as a wildcard to the filename.

Comment: Can you post some minimal example(s) of what you are trying to do?

Comment: "Naive solution: Add wildcards for each possible parameter to the file paths" That's indeed ugly, but that's the obvious way do go for me. Snakemake seems made to work based on file names.

Comment: "Also, that means we need multiple config files for one snakemake call, and it seems that this is not possible (they would instead update each other, but not considered as individual configs to be run separately)." I'm not sure to see why you would need multiple "main" config files. Would a config file containing paths to more config file be useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snakemake now offers the Paramspace helper to solve this! https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html?highlight=parameter#parameter-space-exploration

I have not tried it yet, but it seems like the solution to the issue!